# How do I solve the error CommandInvocationError? Trying to make the discord bot send dog pics using hikari

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
import lightbulb
import requests

bot = lightbulb.BotApp(token="TOKEN")


@bot.command
@lightbulb.command("dog","Dog pictures")
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.SlashCommand)
async def dog(ctx: lightbulb.Context) -> None:
    response = requests.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
    image_link = response.json()["message"]
    await ctx.response(image_link)

bot.run()
```

got the error when trying to execute the command on discord

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xgXY.png)

Comment: Please include the full traceback of any error you are receiving and include a [mcve]. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that `ctx.response` doesn't exist in lightbulb
[image: error]

Just replace the `ctx.response` with `ctx.respond`

Comment: the same error comes up if i use ctx.send or ctx.reply, just says AttributeError: 'SlashContext' object has no attribute 'send'/'reply'

Comment: I edited my answer. Instead of ```ctx.response``` try ```ctx.respond```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
@bot.command
@lightbulb.command("dog","Dog pictures")
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.SlashCommand)
async def dog(ctx: lightbulb.Context) -> None:
    response = requests.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
    image_link = response.json()["message"]
    await ctx.respone(image_link)
```

Comment: Still got the same error